# productCollectionFactory load function gives data in query but not in object

Tags: magento2, product-collection, factory

I have created a collection factory

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',["neq"=>"configurable"]);
```

and after this i calling `load()` function

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
```

and after that applying JOIN's

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
                ['cp' => $collection->getTable('custom_product')], 'e.entity_id = cp.marketplace_product_id'
        );
```

---

some other JOIN's

---

```
$collection->getSelect()->orderRand()->limit(8);
```

> In collection query i am getting perfect query with **JOIN table's data**.

```
foreach ($collection as $key => $data){
    $responce[$key]['custom_price'] = $data->getCustomSpecialPrice();
}
```

I am getting all custom_special_price and other JOIN fields DATA IN Query 
But not in `foreach`.

But when i don't use `load()` function it gives me data using `get` method ,But when i do use `load()` function it doesn't.

**So my question is why Magento loads data in Query ?** But not in Object.